# Left margin including first line

Tags: margins

I'm trying to add margin to text but I have a little problem. I want to get rid of newline after first text. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Text
    \begin{addmargin}[40pt]{0pt}
        \lipsum[11]
    \end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: compiled code]

What I am expecting

[image: expected output]

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: When i see that, i am thinking of a description (or `labeling`) list. Or of marginal notes. Can you explain in more detail, *what* you are trying to achieve instead of saying *how* you can improve what you currently have?

Comment: `\begin{description}\item[Text} Sed ......` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{addmargin}[40pt]{0pt}
  \lipsum[11]
\end{addmargin}

\vskip1cm

\leftskip=40pt\noindent
\llap{\makebox[40pt][l]{Text}}\lipsum[11]

\vskip1cm

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, leftmargin=40pt, labelwidth =\dimexpr40pt-\labelsep\relax]
  \item[Text] \lipsum[11]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Text]
        \lipsum[11]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

the exact indentation and fonts used can be customised by setting the list parameters either directly or more easily using the `enumitem` package, but this shows the basic markup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `addmargin` implementation that you can nest and adjust margins with, and also add "titles" with:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xgalley}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2015/0302-Joseph-Wright/
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetAbsMargins \galley_margins_set_absolute:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetRelMargins \galley_margins_set_relative:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\inserttitle}{}
\newenvironment{addmargin}[2][40pt]
  {%
    \renewcommand{\inserttitle}[1]{%
      \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries ##1}}%
      \ignorespaces}%
  \SetRelMargins{#1}{#2}\ignorespaces}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{addmargin}{0pt}
  \inserttitle{Text}
  \lipsum[11]

  \lipsum[12]

  \begin{addmargin}[75pt]{20pt}
    \inserttitle{More text}
    \lipsum[11]
  \end{addmargin}

  \inserttitle{Text\ldots}
  \lipsum[13]
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

The default left-margin width is 40pt.